# Allow user to Upload image and manipulate it on the frontend

Tags: php, ajax, uploads

The site I am working on allows users to post things up for sale. In the form for creating their post, there is a simple file upload field. The problem is that sometimes when users upload images they end up rotated and they have no way of choosing.

I have put together a php script that will handle the image rotation. I am looking to put together an HTML5 file uploader which I can upload the image on the fly and then send that image to my php script through ajax.

Am I going about this all wrong? If not, is there a plugin for this already or anyone out there that has done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before all of that, I would recommend trying [Image Rotation Repair](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-fixer/) plugin.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, I will give it a go but it hasn't been updated since 2011

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-fixer/ Same thing as what you have posted except its up to date. Add this to your answer and ill mark it accepted.

Comment: Edited the link for your fixer link.